# What is the minimum of this functional？

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Recently I encountered an inequality from mathematical analysis.

Let $f(x)$ be twice continuously differentiable in $[0,1]$ with
$f(0)=f(1)=0$, then for all $x\in(0,1),f(x)\neq 0$, show that:$$\int_{0}^{1}\left | \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} \right |\text{d} x>4.$$

The answer can be obtained by Lagrange Mean Value Theorem, but we can see that $4$ isn't the optimal coefficient for this inequality. So, what is the optimal coefficient of this inequality and when will the equality hold?

I will post the answer of my initial problem. Let $|f(x)|$ get the maximum at $x_0$, the by Lagrange Mean Value Theorem there exist $\xi_1,\xi_2$ such that $\frac{f(x_0)-f(0)}{x_0-0}=f'(\xi_1),\frac{f(x_0)-f(1)}{x_0-1}=f'(\xi_2)$. So we have $$\int_{0}^{1}\left | \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} \right |\text{d} x≥\int_{0}^{1}\left | \frac{f''(x)}{f(x_0)} \right |\text{d} x≥\int_{\xi_1}^{\xi_2}\left | \frac{f''(x)}{f(x_0)} \right |\text{d} x≥\left |\int_{\xi_1}^{\xi_2} \frac{f''(x)}{f(x_0)} \text{d} x\right |=\left | \frac{1}{x_0-1} -\frac{1}{x_0}\right |≥4.$$We can see that the inequality is very weak so I made the assumption that $4$ is not the optimal coefficient but it seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The claim is incorrect. The number $4$ is the optimum constant, and there can be no optimizer in $C^2$**.

***Strategy for proving optimality***: Pretending that $f''$ and $f$ are independent, the quantity $|f'' / f|$ would be minimized when $|f|$ is maximized. So we want to find a function for which $f''$ is signed and concentrated where $f$ is at its maximum. A bit of thought would show that the tent function would satisfy our requirement:
$$ f_{\mathrm{tent}}(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \in [0,1/2] \\ (1-x) & x \in (1/2,1] \end{cases} $$
This function is not $C^2$, but morally speaking has $f'$ with a jump discontinuity and $f'' = -2\delta_{1/2}$. So we expect
$$ \int | f'' / f| = 2 (f(1/2))^{-1} = 4$$
Now we can make the argument precise for $C^2$ functions by mollifying the above example.

---

Let $\chi:[-1,1]\to [0,\infty)$ be an even smooth bump function supported on $[-1/2,1/2]$, with $\int \chi = 2$.

Let $\chi_\epsilon(x) = \frac1\epsilon \chi(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$, so $\int \chi_\epsilon = 2$ and it is supported on $[-\epsilon/2,\epsilon/2]$.

Let $\eta_\epsilon(x) = -1 + \int_{-\frac12}^{x - \frac12} \chi_\epsilon(y) ~dy$, we have that $\eta_\epsilon(0) = -1$ and $\eta_\epsilon(1) = 1$, and since $\chi$ was chosen to be even, we have $\eta_\epsilon(1/2) = 0$ and $\int_{0}^1 \eta_\epsilon = 0$.

Let $f_\epsilon(x) = \int_0^x \eta_\epsilon(y) ~dy$.

We see that $f_\epsilon(0) = f_\epsilon(1) = 0$, $f_\epsilon$ being convex, which implies that $f_\epsilon(x) \neq 0$ for $x\in (0,1)$.

The integral
$$ \int_0^1 \big| \frac{f_\epsilon''(x)}{f_\epsilon(x)} \big| ~dx = \int_{\frac12 (1-\epsilon)}^{\frac12(1+\epsilon)} \big| \frac{f_\epsilon''(x)}{f_\epsilon(x)} \big| ~dx $$
On the interval, we have
$$ |f_\epsilon(x)| \in [\frac12(1-\epsilon),\frac12] $$
and so
$$ \int_{\frac12 (1-\epsilon)}^{\frac12(1+\epsilon)} \big| \frac{f_\epsilon''(x)}{f_\epsilon(x)} \big| ~dx \in \int_0^1 f''_\epsilon \cdot [2, 2(1-\epsilon)^{-1}] = [4, 4(1-\epsilon)^{-1}]$$

Taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ shows that the optimal constant is $4$ (contrary to what you stated).

---

For completeness, we would also need to show that $4$ is a valid lower bound to the integral for all $C^2$ functions. We first note that it suffices to prove
$$ \sup |f| \leq \frac14 \int |f''| \tag{A1}$$
since this would imply
$$ 4 \leq \frac{1}{\sup |f|} \int |f''| \leq \int \frac{|f''|}{|f|}. $$
Several approaches to proving (A1) are given in the comments: [mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461228/what-is-the-minimum-of-this-functional/461230?noredirect=1#comment1196281_461230) and [Giorgio's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461228/what-is-the-minimum-of-this-functional/461230?noredirect=1#comment1196325_461230).

Giorgio's proof also shows that no optimizers can exist in $C^2$: necessarily for an optimizer we need all the inequalities to become an inequality. In particular, for $x_0 = \mathrm{arg\ max} |f|$ we need to make an equality out of
$$ |x_0| \int |f''| \geq  |\int_0^{x_0} x f''| = |f(x_0)| $$
but this is not possible for any continuous function $f''$.

Comment: Incidentally: one can also prove that there cannot be a $C^2$ minimizer. Sketch: suppose for contradiction one exists, then it is not possible that $f'' \equiv 0$, since this would make $f \equiv 0$ with the boundary conditions. So there is an interval on which both $f''$ and $f$ are non vanishing. Taking the first variation with $\delta f$ having compact support in this interval one finds that necessarily a minimizer must satisfy $(f'/f)' = 0$, or $f(x) = C \exp(\omega x)$ for some $C$ and $\omega$. In order for $f$ to be $C^2$, we must have that this ansatz holds for all $(0,1)$....

Comment: ... but this is incompatible with the boundary conditions.

Comment: What is the proof of the inequality in the statement? I do not see it.

Comment: How do you know $\eta_\epsilon(1)=1$? I think the lower and the upper limits of integral don't match.

Comment: @jdhejw $\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \chi_\epsilon = 2$ (for all $\epsilon \leq 1$). And -1 + 2 = 1.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: I had assumed it is obvious when I read the question; but now that I am thinking about it I don't see a clear proof using Lagrange's MVT.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: here's a proof not using MVT. First note that if $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, then letting $x_0$ be the point where $f$ attains its maximum, we find $f(x_0) = \int_0^{x_0} f'(x) = - \int_1^{x_0} f'(x)$ so $2 f(x_0) \leq \int_0^1 |f'(x)| \leq \|f'\|_2$. On the other hand, the boundary conditions also imply $\int f'(x)^2 = - \int f''(x) f(x)$ from which we get $\|f'\|_2^2 \leq \|f''\|_{1} \|f\|_\infty$. Combining we have $4 \|f\|_\infty^2 \leq \|f''\|_1 \|f\|_{\infty} \implies 4 \leq \|f''\|_1 / \|f\|_\infty \leq \int | f'' / f|$.

Comment: Note that the inequality $\|f\|_\infty \leq \frac12 \|f'\|_2$ is sharp (saturated by the tent function centered at $1/2$),  The Holder inequality $| \int f'' f| \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \|f''\|_1$ is also sharp, and this occurs when the support of $f''$ is concentrated where $f$ attains its maximum. In other words, this balances well with the answer I gave above.

Comment: Thank you very much, the proof is clear.

Comment: Maybe a good quick and dirty summary is that if $f$ is the tent peaking at $f(1/2)=1$, then $f''=-4\delta(x-1/2)$, so the integral is "obviously" equal to $4$. (This finishes the proof for the physicist, and the mathematician probably also doesn't have much doubt left that this can be done properly also.)

Comment: Actually the inequality $\|f\|_\infty \leq \frac 14 \|f''\|_1$ can be obtained using Taylor formula centered at the maximum or by writing $$f(x)=(1-x)\int_0^x sf''(s) ds+x \int_x^1 (1-s)f''(s) ds. $$ The maximum of the kernel is $1/4$.

Comment: Or also, if $x_0$ is the maximum point $$f(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x (x-t)f''(t)dt.$$ Evaluating at $x=0,1$ where $f=0$ one gets $$\|f\|_\infty=(1-x_0)\|f\|_\infty +x_0\|f\|_\infty \leq x_0(1-x_0) \int_0^1 |f''| dt \leq \frac{1}{4} \|f''\|_1.$$

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: ah, your [second proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461228/what-is-the-minimum-of-this-functional/461230?noredirect=1#comment1196325_461230) was the first one I tried, but I made a stupid algebraic mistake (on hind sight) so got only the constant $1$ and not $1/4$. Very glad to see that it actually works.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: yes, that was indeed how I first "proved" it. then it took 4 times as long to write out the correct mollifiers. Let me un-hide my tracks and edit this into the answer proper.

Comment: @SamHopkins: your wish is my command.